# Field outside a conductor with Cavity

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

I have a conductor with a cavity inside which a charge $q$ is kept now electrons inside the conductor will rearrange such that net electric field inside the conductor is zero, hence now using Guass law we can say a charge $-q$ is seen at the surface of cavity and by charge conservation a charge +q at surface of conductor , now lets draw a a Guassian surface outside the conductor enclosing it thus $q_{inside}=(+q-q+q)=q$ which is non zero , now this concludes there must be a non zero electric field outside the conductor , I am unable to verify my work here , please confirm that my reasoning as well as conclusions are correct , and also it would be a great help if you provide electric field diagram of above situation(of both outside and inside regions of conductor).

Comment: yes, there will be non zero electric field outside the conductor, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Apart from it being impossible to draw the field diagram without knowing the exact geometry, it is pretty straightforward to describe it in words:  the field lines start to emit from $+q$ in radial direction, then get bent towards the inner surface of the conductor, so that they end perpendicularly at the corresponding surface charges of total $-q$. At the outer surface, the field lines of $+q$ start again perpendicularly and go off to infinity. For simple geometries you can probably use mirror charges to construct the field (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges).